# Gulp перестал работать

Tags: node.js, gulp

Неожиданно перестал работать gulp в node.js.
До сегодняшнего дня все работал прекрасно... Но сейчас, при попытке собрать проект выдает следующую ошибку:

[image: Ошибка]

Настройки gulp:

[image: Настройки gulp]

Переустанавливал node.js, сносил node_modules ставил заново, ковырял настройки, ничего на работу так и не повлияло.

В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мда уж... Поигрался с настройками, называется.

Проблема была в том, что меняя пути к node.js я по незнанию поменял путь до gulp директории. Достаточно было в gulp package поменять путь до gulp в node_modules.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Спасибо за внимание